# If it possible to permanently set a loose source routing option to all ip packages to a specific ip address?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ip

First of all, the [loose source routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_Source_Routing) is a kind of ip options which requires a selected hop to route this package.

I wonder if it possible to set loose source routing option on specific ip packages(e.g. packages that are to send to a specific address) with iproute2 or netfilter-tools(like iptables or firewalld)? If it possible, how can I make it?

By the way, [source routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_routing) is not source based routing! The former has nothing about receive a package from other hosts and route it.